# How to renumber html4 anchor tags using XSLT2 to reference document page numbers not physical pages?

Tags: xslt-2.0

There are anchor tags on each page of the document that relate back to the TOC, but they are located on the cover page also, so that anchor page 1 is the cover. I need the 3rd physical page (sumpage1) to be anchor page 1. How do I reset the anchor tags to make document page 1 be the 3rd page and the subsequent anchor numbers reset too follow the new sumpage1 numbering?

Desired result:

```
    <Hpage Hplname="cover">
        <DIV style="padding: 4pt; width: 98%; display: block;">
            <P style="font: 8pt Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;">

            </P>

    <Hpage Hplname="sumpage1">
        <DIV style="padding: 4pt; width: 98%; display: block;">
            <P style="font: 8pt Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;">
                <A href="#tocpage">Back to Contents</A>
                <A name="toc1"/>
            </P>
```

Following sumpage1 page allpagel should be toc2 (and so on):

```
    <Hpage Hplname="allpagel">
        <DIV style="padding: 4pt; width: 98%; display: block;">
            <P style="font: 8pt Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;">
                <A href="#tocpage">Back to Contents</A>
                <A name="toc4"/>
            </P>
```

Comment: If the input is a posted, can you show us the result you want to create with XSLT 2.0 for that input snippet? Do you want to have `<A name="toc1"/>` inside `Hpage Hplname="sumpage1"`? What is supposed to happen with `<A name="toc1"/>` inside `Hpage Hplname="cover"`?

Comment: Desired result:  <Hpage Hplname="cover">
        <DIV style="padding: 4pt; width: 98%; display: block;">
            <P style="font: 8pt Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;">
                </P>

    <Hpage Hplname="sumpage1">
        <DIV style="padding: 4pt; width: 98%; display: block;">
            <P style="font: 8pt Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;">
                <A href="#tocpage">Back to Contents</A>
                <A name="toc1"/>
            </P>

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there so that we can read it better.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

plus an empty

```
<xsl:template match="Hpage[@Hplname = 'cover']//A[@name]"/>
```

to remove the anchor from the cover and

```
<xsl:template match="Hpage[not(@Hplname = 'cover')]//A[@name]">
  <xsl:variable name="count" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:number count="Hpage[not(@Hplname = 'cover')]//A[@name]" level="any"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <A name="toc{$count}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to number the anchors inside the `Hpage` elements.

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @randola: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.